# What are Padé approximants and how are they used for series acceleration?

Tags: pi, pade-approximation, convergence-acceleration

I read an article about [series acceleration on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration). I found in the non-linear acceleration section that Padé approximants can be used for series acceleration. But I am not able to understand what it is, and how it accelerates series. For understanding purposes, can someone explain to me with an example of the [Leibniz series for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80)?

Comment: sorry if any details left.. Please tell if so

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you know the basics of Taylor/MacLaurin series expansion.

The Leibniz formula for $\pi$ (or rather, $\pi/4$) is obtained from substiuting $x=1$ into
$$
f(x):=\arctan x=x-\frac13x^3+\frac15x^5-\frac17x^7+\dots
$$
So we will try to find a way of accelerating the convergence of this series by replacing the partial sum
$$
S_n=f_n(1),\quad f_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1}x^{2j+1}
$$
by something which looks like $f_n$ for small enough $x$, namely the [Padé approximants $[m/n]_f$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) and taking appropriate subsequences of the doubly-indexed $([m/n]_f(1))_{m,n}$.  Now there are various ways to do this, some better than others.  However, it is probably a good idea to try to do it via some diagonal-ish way, so let's try $[n+1/n]_f$, the numerator having one higher degree than the denominator since $\arctan x\approx x$ is a reasonably good first approximation.

Padé approximants are quite efficiently computed by the Wynn's $\varepsilon$-algorithm: initialize
$$
\varepsilon^{(n)}_{-1}=0, \varepsilon^{(n)}_0=f_n,\quad n=0,1,2,\dots
$$
and compute
$$
\varepsilon^{(n)}_{k+1}=\varepsilon^{(n-1)}_{k-1}+\big[\varepsilon^{(n+1)}_k-\varepsilon^{(n)}_k\big]^{-1}
$$
Then $\varepsilon^{(n)}_{2k}=[n+k/k]_f$.

So we obtain, for example,
\begin{align*}
[1/0]_f&=x\\
[3/2]_f&=\frac{105x+40x^3-4x^5}{105+75x^2}\\
[5/4]_f&=\frac{945 x + 735 x^3 + 64 x^5}{945 + 1050 x^2 + 225 x^4}\\
[7/6]_f&=\frac{15015 x + 19250 x^3 + 5943 x^5 + 256 x^7}{15015 + 24255 x^2 + 11025 x^4 + 1225 x^6}
\end{align*}
which gives us approximations of $\pi$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
[m/n] & 4[m/n]_f(1) & \text{rel. error}\\\hline
[1/0] & 4 & 27.3\%\\
[3/2] & \frac{19}{6}     = 3.166666666\dots&0.798\%\\
[5/4] & \frac{1744}{555} = 3.142342342\dots&0.024\%\\
[7/6] & \frac{2529}{805} = 3.141614906\dots&0.001\%
\end{array}
$$

Similarly, if you want to start at a higher degree numerator, we have
\begin{align*}
[3/0]_f&=x-\frac13x^3\\
[5/2]_f&=\frac{105x+40x^3-4x^5}{105+75x^2}\\
[7/4]_f&=\frac{10395x + 9765x^3 + 1344x^5 - 64x^7}{10395 + 13230x^2 + 3675x^4}\\
[9/6]_f&=\frac{225225x + 330330x^3 + 128205x^5 - 256x^7 + 9216x^9}{225225 + 405405x^2 + 218295x^4 - 33075x^6}
\end{align*}
and
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
[m/n] & 4[m/n]_f(1)\\\hline
[3/0] & \frac{8}{3}=2.666666666\dots\\
[5/2] & \frac{47}{15} = 3.133333333\dots\\
[7/4] & \frac{4288}{1365} = 3.141391941\dots\\
[9/6] & \frac{4948}{1575} = 3.141587301\dots
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks but i am confused how did you calculated the Pade approximant would be more helpfull if you can show all the steps for m = 7 and n = 6 for understanding purpose or any other example

Comment: You calculate using Wynn's $\epsilon$-algorithm.  I've given you the recursion formula (note that $\varepsilon_{2k+1}$'s are just intermediary and doesn't play any role).  So we start with $\varepsilon_{-1}$ (zeros) and $\varepsilon_0$ (partial sums, up to $x^{7+6}=x^{13}$), and the sequence $\varepsilon^{(n)}_1$ (you need up to $n=12$ here) is calculated from $\varepsilon_0$ and $\varepsilon_{-1}$ sequences, now calculate the sequence $\varepsilon_2$ from $\varepsilon_0$ and $\varepsilon_1$, ... until you get $\varepsilon_{12}$ and read off $\varepsilon_{12}^{(1)}$ for $[7/6]_f$.

Comment: can you help me programing this in python in this link :- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247444/pad%c3%a9-approximants-as-acceleration-for-lebniez-series-of-pi